# Как обновлять данные в приложении при их обновлении на сервере

Tags: php, android

Хочу сделать свой чат. Для опыта. Делал простой запрос на сервер на php. Получал сообщения. Но чтобы пришли новые сообщения нужно обновить лист сообщений, то есть делать новый запрос на сервер. Как сделать так, чтобы сообщения приходили сами, без повторного запроса, как в любых месенджерах?
В начале думал, что это делается тем, что каждую минуту делается запрос на сервер, но потом подумал и понял что это извращение.

Есть ли решения этому вопросу на php? Именно на php, потому что у меня бесплатный сервер на php.

Comment: Не надо тут выкладывать свои душераздирающие истории о жизни, пожалуйста. Чисто по делу: проблема такая то, делал так то, получилось то то, а должно вот так .. PS: еще запятых отсыпал

Comment: один из тех, кого ваши [пространные введения не по существу вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/95/177345) не устраивают

Comment: я задал вопрос так чтобы не было непоняток. Люди добрые увидели и ответили. Я получил свое. С первого же раза если бы я писал как вы хотите то было бы много вопросов мне

Comment: @user8978194 вопрос: зачем, чтобы ответить на конкретный четко заданный вопрос нам нужно знать что вы там учили, после чего это было, во сколько вы в туалет ходите и по каким числам желудок промываете?

Comment: Да, без объяснения всей той мути вашего тернистого пути к этому вопросу и правда бы никто ничего не понял. Так же рекомендую ознакомиться, как [здесь задавать вопросы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), а особенно, что должен содержать заголовок, чтобы получать меньше минусов.

Comment: @pavloff Я не знал как объяснить. В любом случае извиняюсь

Comment: @user8978194 всегда излагайте суть: "есть такая-то проблема - как решить, как поступить, что нужно сделать?"

Comment: Еще вы должны осознавать, что этот ресурс не вконтактик, здесь много людей взрослых, которые работают в IT-сфере, они читают ваши сообщения, вопросы и ответы. Что бы вы хотели, чтобы о вас подумали? как вам ответили, захотели бы помочь ..  в общем, думайте, что пишите и кто это увидит, пожалуйста.

Comment: @pavloff матом ругаться можно?

Comment: @user8978194 матом ругаться можно, но не долго, до прихода модератора, потом неделя отдыха, потом снова можно ругаться, затем год отдыха

Comment: если вы хотите показаться умным, то лучше вам по-русски писать грамотно, чем задавать "провокационные" вопросы. Это оценит большее количество человек.

Comment: @pavloff если бы я хотел показаться умным я бы не говорил что мои познание ограничиваются пхп и ява. Я извенился? ДА. Че то не нравиться можете закрывать вопрос я против ничего не имею. По крайней мере лучше чем нудить

Comment: @user8978194, тут никто не нудит. Мы все пытаемся вам помочь, указывая, какие есть проблемы в вашем вопросе. Цель - помочь вам так задавать вопросы, чтобы они получили максимальный шанс получить ответ по существу. А этому точно не способствует лирика и занимательные истории из жизни.

Comment: проблема в том, что никто здесь не стремится помочь лично вам, после публикации вопросы (и ответы) принадлежат сообществу. Цель данного ресурса - создать базу проблем и решений, то есть другой человек, с аналогичной проблемой, сможет быстро решить ее, найдя этот вопрос (и решение) по адекватному заголовку (а не не вменяемому "Совет новичку.ПХП"). Вот зачем мы здесь и ваше личное за или против тут влияет в последней степени

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Вы должны прочитать про Socket.io. Если использовать сокеты, то вам обновлять ничего не нужно

Comment: увидел реализацию на пхп. Я кажется понимаю как работает это. Есть ли какой нить пример или док.  как написать правильно на андроиде?

Comment: @user8978194, `Я кажется понимаю как работает это. ` - это как я понимаю, но не знаю? Странный коммент. Изучайте работу серверных сокетов. Как взаимодействует клиент <> сервер приложения.

Comment: Я на nodeJS & Angular-e писал с сокетами, но в php и  android я не юзал

Comment: Конкретно упоминание socket.io здесь ни к чему, т.к это js-бибилиотека.

Comment: В чем трудность подключить  JS на php?